# Passing a Type into a method to fill an object

Tags: c#, xml, methods, types

I can't figure out how to pass a type into a method and get back an object's value. I've got a snippet of code here to write to an xml file:

```
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MG_GameData));
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream (Application.dataPath + "/Data/MG_Data.data", FileMode.Open);
        //load the data into our temp object
        mg_GameDataTemp = xmlSerializer.Deserialize (fileStream) as MG_GameData;
        //close file
        fileStream.Close ();
```

I'm trying to re-write this to be a method, but I don't know how to actually do it:

```
public class XML { 

public static object open(Type type, string path) { 
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MG_GameData));
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream (path, FileMode.Open);
    object TempObject = xmlSerializer.Deserialize (fileStream) as type;
    fileStream.Close ();
    return TempObject;
}

public static void save() {

}
}
```

The reason being is this line of code here:

```
object TempObject = xmlSerializer.Deserialize (fileStream) as type;
```

You can't pass the value 'type' there.

I'm wondering why this is, and how I could fix this method so that it works...

Comment: Post a sample of your classes you are using.

Comment: I don't know that that would help to answer the question. I don't know that I can make the question any clearer than I have. The last code snippet won't allow me to put the 'type' value in that place...I'm not understanding why that is.

Comment: XML serializer expects code to contain a hierarchy of classes predefined.  It will not automatically create the classes.

Comment: Oh okay, I see...Hmmm...So there's no way of having the above static method work by passing in the Type? Maybe if I used reflection?

Comment: Jason Deseializer will work.

Comment: Thanks for the help jdweng : )

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generic method to pass in a type:

```
public static T open<T>(string path) where T : class {
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)) {
        return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
    }
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
var data = open<MG_GameData>("data.xml");
```

You can find a lot about generics in the web, for example [this official programming guide from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/generics/).